# How to prevent a 32x32 fixed sized SurfaceView from being anti-aliased?

Tags: android

I'm trying to use a 32x32 fixed sized `SurfaceView` for a live preview. Stretching the `SurfaceView` to fill its square parent layout causes the system to apply anti-aliasing. Is there a way to prevent the anti-aliasing from happening?

Here's a sample code:

```kotlin
// during surface view initialization
holder.setFixedSize(32, 32)

// on surfaceChanged
holder.lockCanvas().apply {
    try {
        // canvasPaint: isAntiAlias = false, isFilterBitmap = false
        drawPaint(canvasPaint)

        // linePaint: color = Color.RED, isAntiAlias = false, isFilterBitmap = false
        drawLine(0f, 0f, 32f, 32f, linePaint)
    } finally {
        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(this)
    }
}
```

and here's how it's rendered on the screen:
[image: Sample code's output]

and here's how I want it to be rendered on the screen:
[image: Expected output]

Answer (score 0):

If Android needs to magnify an image, anti-aliasing is the default setting. You must deactivate this property by setting the following fourth parameter `filter` to `false`:

```java
imageViewMagnification.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapOriginal, windowWidth, windowHeight, false));
```

Answer (score 0):

*The following solution requires at least API 29!*

I ended up using an `ImageReader`, together with a `RenderNode` and a `HardwareRenderer`, to "produce" a `Bitmap` every time the live preview needs to be updated. The `Bitmap` I get from each update can then be drawn on a hardware accelerated `Canvas` using `drawBitmap` with a non-null `Paint`. The `isFilterBitmap` property is set to `false` of the said `Paint` instance to disable anti-aliasing of scaled bitmaps.

There's no need for me to use a fixed sized `SurfaceView` anymore with this solution because the `ImageReader` instance is now the one created with the 32x32 size and bitmaps can be drawn on arbitrary sized canvas.

```kotlin
// Renderer initialization
val imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(
    32, // width
    32, // height
    PixelFormat.RGBA_8888,
    5, // max images, 
    HardwareBuffer.USAGE_GPU_SAMPLED_IMAGE or
        HardwareBuffer.USAGE_GPU_COLOR_OUTPUT,
)
val contentRenderNode = RenderNode("content").apply {
    setPosition(0, 0, 32, 32)
}
val hardwareRenderer = HardwareRenderer().apply {
    // The result of the render requests we create
    //     using this hardware renderer is sent to the
    //     ImageReader and can be received by calling
    //     ImageReader#acquireLatestImage or 
    //     ImageReader#acquireNextImage
    setSurface(imageReader.surface)
    setContentRoot(contentRenderNode)
}
val contentBitmapPaint = Paint().apply {
    isFilterBitmap = false // IMPORTANT!
}

// =================

// SurfaceView initialization
// holder.setFixedSize(32, 32) // I DON'T NEED THIS ANYMORE!

// =================

// When a live preview update request is received, I record
//     the canvas operations using the RenderNode and submit a
//     render request
contentRenderNode.beginRecording().apply {
    try {
        // -- I AM NOW DOING ALL THE RENDERING STUFF HERE --
        drawLine(0f, 0f, 32f, 32f, linePaint)
    } finally {
        contentRenderNode.endRecording()
    }
}
hardwareRenderer.createRenderRequest()
    // I'm not going to wait because I'm on a different thread
    .setWaitAndPresent(false)
    .syncAndDraw()

// =================

// Update the SurfaceView with the latest live preview content
imageReader.acquireLatestImage()?.use { image ->
    image.hardwareBuffer?.use { hardwareBuffer ->
        val contentBitmap = checkNotNull(
            Bitmap.wrapHardwareBuffer(hardwareBuffer)
        )
        try {
            // Hardware accelerated canvas is needed so the
            //     bitmap wrapped hardware buffer can be drawn
            //     on the canvas
            val canvas = holder.lockHardwareCanvas()
            try {
                // Upscale the 32x32 bitmap from the ImageReader
                //     to the width and height of canvas without
                //     applying bitmap filtering/anti-aliasing
                drawBitmap(
                    contentBitmap, 
                    null, // equivalent to Rect(0, 0, 32, 32)
                    Rect(0, 0, width, height),
                    contentBitmapPaint,
                )
            } finally {
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas)
            }
        } finally {
            contentBitmap.recycle()
        }
    }
}
```

If you know a better way to do this, preferably simpler and more efficient, please let me know! Comments are very much appreciated.